# wso2 IS Table 'wso2.sp_app' doesn't exist

Tags: wso2

I am trying to get started with WS02 IdentityServer 5.0. I have changed the default data source to mysql 5.6. I have executed the scripts in wso2is-5.0.0\dbscripts\mysql.sql and wso2is-5.0.0\dbscripts\identity\mysql.sql.

The server starts up without errors. However, when I try to create a user from local dashboard the below exception is thrown.  What am i missing here? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
 [2015-07-08 16:19:25,729] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.OutboundProvisioningManager} -  Error while out-bound provisioning.
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: Failed to update service provider 0
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl.getApplication(ApplicationDAOImpl.java:1090)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationInfoProvider.getServiceProvider(ApplicationInfoProvider.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.OutboundProvisioningManager.provision(OutboundProvisioningManager.java:343)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.provisioning.listener.DefaultInboundUserProvisioningListener.doPreAddUser(DefaultInboundUserProvisioningListener.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1063)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1022)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1164)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.UserRegistrationService.addUser(UserRegistrationService.java:231)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.UserRegistrationService.addUser(UserRegistrationService.java:162)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver.java:66)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'wso2.sp_app' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:372)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:980)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3835)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3771)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1911)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl.getBasicApplicationData(ApplicationDAOImpl.java:1121)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl.getApplication(ApplicationDAOImpl.java:1042)
        ... 52 more
[2015-07-08 16:19:29,520] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in A
uthentication Framework
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.FrameworkException: Error while reading application
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.builder.UIBasedConfigurationBuilder.getSequence(UIBasedConfigurationBuilder.java
:77)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.ConfigurationFacade.getSequenceConfig(ConfigurationFacade.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.findPreviousAuthenticatedSession(Default
RequestCoordinator.java:212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.initializeFlow(DefaultRequestCoordinator
.java:201)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:61
)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:51)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.IdentityApplicationManagementException: Error while reading application
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.dao.impl.ApplicationDAOImpl.getServiceProviderNameByClientId(ApplicationDAOImpl.java:2293)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationInfoProvider.getServiceProviderNameByClientId(ApplicationInfoProvider.java:150)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ApplicationInfoProvider.getServiceProviderByClienId(ApplicationInfoProvider.java:209)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.config.builder.UIBasedConfigurationBuilder.getSequence(UIBasedConfigurationBuilder.java
:75)
        ... 40 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved after running wso2is-5.0.0\dbscripts\identity\application-mgt\mysql.sql.

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem with Postgresql, too. Those files seem to have SQL syntax errors, but I could fix them.